# Google Sheet Query Function - Combine 2 Steps together in Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Pl. refer the Sheet shared below -
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r0_oHLTcT9tmTJPgKVgkGwGWhooBM8uluwmWcC92eOk/edit?usp=sharing

Rank for diff. factors is calculated in Rank Sheet in Table A. Rank!ColL calculates combine score (D+ G + J).
PF Sheet Range - Z:AE have Step wise calculation and results expected.

1 - Objective is to get results of used Query(Rank!C8:L220,"Select C,L where D > F12 & L > 0.5 order by L desc",1)   (ref. cell PF Sheet!AE17).
Query is referencing RANK Sheet's Cols.

2 - Possibility of merging Combine Score calculation as base data in Query.

Do revert is more clarity is reqd.

Comment: please, share a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Pl. refer 'P f Sheet' Z:AE Cols - Steps and output is  given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reviewed the Sheet, and I can make some suggestions.

Since you are calling 2 columns with the Query, add 1 column to the right of AE, and that one will be the new AF.

After that, modify the formula from:

```
=query(Rank!C8:L220,"Select C,L where D > 0.25 & L > 0.5 order by L desc",1)
```

to:

```
=query(Rank!C8:L220,"Select C,L where D > 0.25 and L > 0.5 order by L desc",1)
```

The reason it was not working is the use of `&` instead of `and` as mentioned [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en#:%7E:text=of%20Salary.-,Headers,-Specifies%20the%20number).

[image]

To make reference to a specific Cell instead of a value. You can use `"&F12&"`, Like this:

[image]

**Reference**

- [QUERY function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Giselle. How to put greater than (or less then ) condition referenced to a cell value....i.e. ?D > cell value of F12", in this case.

Comment: I edited the answer with the change.